# JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string_of_json_array);

Tags: java, json, parsing, arraylist, foreach

I am trying to parse Json arraylist(children) in Java using GSON and a for loop. 
But I am getting the following error:

```
for each not applicable to expression type
required:array or java.lang.iterable
found:String
```

Here is the main Java Class which displays this error

```
 try {
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("user.json"));
     Tree result = gson.fromJson(br, Tree.class);

    if (result !=null){  
      for (User t : result.getCategory()){  //ERROR IS HERE (squiggly red line)
         System.out.println(t.getId() + "-" + t.getName() + "-" + t.getCategory() + "-" + t.getPercentage());  //ERROR IS ALSO HERE FOR EACH VARIABLES
     }
    }


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (br != null){

      try {
          br.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
```

This is the Tree Class:

```
    private String category;
@SerializedName("children")
@Expose
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

public String getCategory() {
return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
this.category = category;
}

public List<Child> getChildren() {
return children;
}

public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
this.children = children;
}
```

User Class:

```
 private String id;
@SerializedName("processed_lang")
@Expose
private String processedLang;
@SerializedName("source")
@Expose
private String source;
@SerializedName("tree")
@Expose
private Tree tree;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getProcessedLang() {
return processedLang;
}

public void setProcessedLang(String processedLang) {
this.processedLang = processedLang;
}

public String getSource() {
return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
this.source = source;
}

public Tree getTree() {
return tree;
}

public void setTree(Tree tree) {
this.tree = tree;
}
    String getName() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

Can someone let me know where I went wrong and if you guys want to see the json code let me know I will also place it and the reason I didn't place it is because its very long.So how can I get the array list children to show? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `getCategory` returns a String but you're trying to iterate over it in your `for` loop. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that ..I am trying to display the Arraylist Children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `For-Each` loop in Java object which is going to be iterated has to implement `Iterable<T>` interface.

To iterate through `children` (as you mentioned in the comment) just use:

```
for (Child child : result.getChildren()){             
    System.out.println(child);
}
```

`List<T>` implements Iterable interface so you can use for-each loop with it.

Read more: [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but is there a way to make the Arraylist from class Tree to display? as that will probably show all the arrays. Child only shows one arraylist.

Comment: @ArdiAbdul sorry, I can't get the point. What you would like to have?